# How to list all used operations in Tensorflow SavedModel?

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I save my model using the `tensorflow.saved_model.save` function in SavedModel format, how can I retrieve which Tensorflow Ops are used in this model afterwards. As the model can be restored, these operations are stored in the graph, my guess is in the `saved_model.pb` file. If I load this protobuf (so not the entire model) the library part of the protobuf lists these, but this is not documented and tagged as an experimental feature for now. Models created in Tensorflow 1.x won't have this part.

So what is a fast and reliable way to retrieve a list of used Operations (Like `MatchingFiles` or `WriteFile`) from a model in SavedModel format?

Right now I can freeze the entire thing, like [`tensorflowjs-converter`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/0839b62e17e57c771501a0861b0d44bde59a51ed/tfjs-converter/python/tensorflowjs/converters/tf_saved_model_conversion_v2.py#L298-L315) does. As they also check for supported Operations. This currently does not work when an LSTM is in the model, see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36391). Is there a better way to do this, as the Ops are definitely in there?

An example model:

```
class FileReader(tf.Module):

@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(name='filename', shape=[None], dtype=tf.string)])
def read_disk(self, file_name):
    input_scalar = tf.reshape(file_name, [])
    output = tf.io.read_file(input_scalar)
    return tf.stack([output], name='content')

file_reader = FileReader()

tf.saved_model.save(file_reader, 'file_reader')
```

Expected in output all Ops, containing in this case at least:

- `ReadFile` as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/read-file)
- ...

Comment: It is hard to tell exactly what you want, what is `saved_model.pb`, is it a `tf.GraphDef`, or a `SavedModel` protobuf message? If you have a `tf.GraphDef` called `gd`, you can get the list of used ops with `sorted(set(n.op for n in gd.node))`. If you have a loaded model, you can do `sorted(set(op.type for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()))`. If it is a `SavedModel`, you can get the `tf.GraphDef` from it (e.g. `saved_model.meta_graphs[0].graph_def`).

Comment: I want to retrieve the ops from a stored SavedModel. So indeed, the last option you are describing. What is the `saved_model` variable in your last example? The result of `tf.saved_model.load('/path/to/model')` or loading the protobuf of the saved_model.pb file.

Answer (score 4):

If `saved_model.pb` is a `SavedModel` protobuf message, then you get the operations directly from there. Let's say we create a model as follows:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class FileReader(tf.Module):
    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(name='filename', shape=[None], dtype=tf.string)])
    def read_disk(self, file_name):
        input_scalar = tf.reshape(file_name, [])
        output = tf.io.read_file(input_scalar)
        return tf.stack([output], name='content')

file_reader = FileReader()
tf.saved_model.save(file_reader, 'tmp')
```

We can now find the operations used by that model like this:

```py
from tensorflow.core.protobuf.saved_model_pb2 import SavedModel

saved_model = SavedModel()
with open('tmp/saved_model.pb', 'rb') as f:
    saved_model.ParseFromString(f.read())
model_op_names = set()
# Iterate over every metagraph in case there is more than one
for meta_graph in saved_model.meta_graphs:
    # Add operations in the graph definition
    model_op_names.update(node.op for node in meta_graph.graph_def.node)
    # Go through the functions in the graph definition
    for func in meta_graph.graph_def.library.function:
        # Add operations in each function
        model_op_names.update(node.op for node in func.node_def)
# Convert to list, sorted if you want
model_op_names = sorted(model_op_names)
print(*model_op_names, sep='\n')
# Const
# Identity
# MergeV2Checkpoints
# NoOp
# Pack
# PartitionedCall
# Placeholder
# ReadFile
# Reshape
# RestoreV2
# SaveV2
# ShardedFilename
# StatefulPartitionedCall
# StringJoin
```

Comment: I tried something like this, but unfortunately this does not what I expect it does: Say I have a model that does this: `input_scalar = tf.reshape(file_name, [])
        output = tf.io.read_file(input_scalar)
        return tf.stack([output], name='content')` Then the ReadFile Op as listed [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/read-file) is in there, but is not printed.

Comment: @sampers I have edited the answer with an example like you suggest. I do get the `ReadFile` operation in the output. Is it possible that, in your actual case, that operation is not between the input and the output of the saved model? In that case I think it might get pruned.

Comment: Indeed with the given model it works. Unfortunately for a module made in tf2, it does not. If I create a tf.Module with 1 function with a `file_name` argument `@tf.function` annotation, containing the calls I listed in my previous comment, it gives the following list: `Const, NoOp, PartitionedCall, Placeholder, StatefulPartitionedCall`

Comment: added a model to my question

Comment: @sampers I have updated my answer. I was using TF 1.x before, I wasn't familiar with the changes to graph definition objects in TF 2.x, I think the answer now covers everything in the saved model. I think the operations corresponding to the Python function that you wrote are in `saved_model.meta_graphs[0].graph_def.library.function[0]` (the `node_def` collection within that function object).

Comment: Yes they are in there, but as stated in my question this part is listed as `// EXPERIMENTAL. DO NOT USE OR DEPEND ON THIS YET.` So I was looking for another way to do this, that might not be removed.

Comment: @sampers Ahh so that is what you meant by "the library part of the protobuf lists these", I thought you meant some experimental API in the library that retrieved these. The thing is, it is experimental because all of this stuff (serializing models) is experimental in TF 2.x (which I find kinda baffling considering it was a well-established feature even back in TF 0.x). For now, there is that, they may change it, and change the related code accordingly. The information is not anywhere else. If you stick to the same version it should still work, may stop working after some update ‍♂️